# C# foreach closures and csc.exe /langversion:4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, closures

This question is related to [Why is there a difference in behaviour of an application built in VS 2010 v.s. VS 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976934/why-is-there-a-difference-in-behaviour-of-an-application-built-in-vs-2010-v-s-v)
but in my case I have vs 2010 and 2013 installed (both professional).

According to the answer from the referenced question it is because of the different c# versions. But compiling and running the code from command line :

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
        var texts = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };


        foreach (var text in texts)
        {
            funcs.Add(delegate { return text; });
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(funcs.ToList()[i]());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

With **csc /out:My.exe /langversion:4 Program.cs** gives me the same **1,2,3** output as with **/langversion:5** and **/langversion:3**

Running with vs 2010 with target framework dot net 4 client profile, gives me **3,3,3**
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: [The purpose of the /langversion is only to make the compiler accept specific language constructs. It does not affect the actual behaviour of the compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476057/how-to-compile-c-sharp-with-specific-language-version). You need to use a different `csc.exe` to achieve the same behavior as the respective Visual Studio version.

Comment: What is the output when you move funcs.ToList() outside for loop and assign to a variable and use that variable instead in for loop??